# rtlwifi compilation on Debian 7

Tags: debian, drivers, compiling

I use Debian 7 Wheezy, and I have an error when I try to type `make` command.

**I am trying to compile `rtlwifi` driver.**

This is the error message:

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:57: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to fix it?

Comment: @MuhammadRompegadink Please put as much information to the question as you can, because otherwise we don't know what you are trying to do. I took the liberty of editing your question to a more appropriate format.

Comment: @MuhammadRompegadink What is your exact model of wifi card? And why do you still use Debian 7?

Comment: @Vlastimil it's pretty unclear. Question edits will get it reviewed for re-open.

Comment: did you install those : "make", "gcc", "kernel headers", "kernel build essentials", and "git". as mention in documentation. Also keep in mind that Debian 7 is no longer supported. you might consider to update your OS

Answer (score 1):

You need to install your kernel’s headers: run

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

as root.

Comment: Hi Stephen. I am wondering if it would not be easier just to install the `firmware-realtek` package?

Comment: @Vlastimil that’s a very good point; it depends on what problem the OP is really trying to solve, and whether the driver and firmware available in Wheezy (or Wheezy backports, which has the same firmware as Jessie) support the hardware being used.

Comment: `build-essential` rather than just the headers?

Comment: @roaima given that the OP already has `make`, I imagine the compiler and co. are installed too. The error is caused by the absence of the kernel headers, and only that. (Of course there may be other errors later on, once that’s fixed...)

Comment: Sure no worries. Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in *backports* containing this WiFi driver. You should just need to [add it](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) to your `sources.list` and then install it.

```
echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free' >>/etc/apt/sources.list.s/wheezy-backports
apt-get update
apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

Remember that this all has to be done as root. (Use `sudo -s` or `su -` to get there.)

---

<sub>Not directly answering your question, but trying to help solve what seems to be the underlying issue.</sub>

Comment: That package doesn’t contain the driver.